# How to remove the :port number from the end of an IIS URL?

Tags: url, iis, port

In IIS, I noticed when you use the default ports (**80** for http and **443** for https) the port number doesn't display at the end of the URL in your browser. However, if you use a different port it *will* display.

Example:
Default port generates link: http://www.example.com

Custom port generates link: http://www.example.com:8301

Is there a setting you can change to make the port (in this case, **:8301**) not display without using the defaults?

Comment: The port number is a significant part of the URL - it's not an optionally displayed item and not related to IIS. For non-standard ports, the number must be included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

80 is a default port for HTTP connections.
`http://example.com` = `http://example.com:80`

443 is a default port for HTTPS connections.
`https://example.com` = `https://example.com:443`

If you are hosting on an other port, you **have to** include it in the URL.
It's not a IIS rule - it's about HTTP in general. You cannot configure the server in such way that http://example.com will work with port 8301 and I can't imagine any situation when it can be useful. I strongly believe that 80 port is chosen by default on a browser-side but not assigned on a server-side.

If you want users to reach this website by `http://example.com` URL and it must be a main page then swap your 8301 and 80 ports WebSites' bindings.

Comment: a use in case is when a load balancer is on port 80 and the actual application is on a different port.  There are url rewrite rules for switching the application, but i'm having trouble with internal hard-coded links (generated by the application) i need a rule to rewrite the port number.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Can I rewrite/redirect some sub domain name to specific port using url rewrite?

Comment: @Kumaan: You will face issue If you use a proxy - which handle https and a server running apache for host the app and iis for reverting proxy