# Remove the custom port number from https url using IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I have a site which is configured in IIS7. Currently, the site named Site1, which uses the https protocol with a custom port number 5001. I can access this site by using the url given below:

```
https://demo.mydomain.com:5001/Site1
```

I need to eliminate the port number from the url, but it should access the same content which is used by the url "https://demo.mydomain.com:5001/Site1".

```
Expected result should be like this: "https://demo.mydomain.com/Site1"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673359/how-to-remove-the-port-number-from-the-end-of-an-iis-url.

Answer (score -1):

In IIS Manager, click on the Site (left pane) and the click Bindings (right pane).  You'll see a binding for port 5001.  Edit that binding to be port 443.   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)

My guess though is you have some other site that is bound to port 443, if that is the case you either need to remove it from the other site, or if you need them to coexist, you need to dig into SNI which is a bit more advanced topic ([SNI and SSL on IIS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406326/sni-and-ssl-on-iis-8-5))

Comment: SNI is not available in IIS 7.

Comment: That's true Lex Li, but people often use the term IIS 7 to refer to everything IIS 7+.   My statement is still true though that if they want to host multiple sites on the same ip/port on HTTPS differing only by hostname, they need SNI.

Comment: Anyway, I don't know much about SNI. Need checking about that. Thanks for your support.